# Only initialise jQuery below screen size, destruct or terminate above

Tags: jquery, responsive, flexnav

I'm trying to run the script 'flexnav' on screens below 960 pixels only.

It works as it should if you load on screens >= 960 and then initialises correctly when resized below 960. However, once the screen gets resized back over 960 the script is still initialised breaking the layout.

How do I destruct/terminate flexnav from working after resize above 960?

```
$(window).resize(function() {
        if($(window).width() < 960) {
             jQuery(".flexnav").flexNav();
        } else {


        }
});
```

Comment: You need to use a variable to remember whether you previously initialized it, and then destroy it when the width is large.

Comment: I took a quick look at the code, it doesn't seem to have a way to remove it. The best you can do is change some of the options when the size is higher than 960.